# How to fix "remote: ssl required" when pushing to Bitbucket?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am getting the above error whenever I try to push my changes. I am using TortoiseHg as client.

Here is the debug output for `hg push`:

```
pushing to https://nulldev@bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
using https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
proxying through http://[proxy - omitted]
http auth: user nulldev, password not set    
sending capabilities command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Looking for password for user nulldev and url https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Keyring password found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
query 1; heads    
sending batch command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
searching for changes    
all remote heads known locally    
sending branchmap command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
sending branchmap command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"    
sending listkeys command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
1 changesets found    
list of changesets:
35b9240f7e7a5eee7936d8559962971e94fab1fc    
bundling: 1/1 changesets (100.00%)    
bundling: 1/1 manifests (100.00%)    
bundling: Key Ring/Controls/BindableApplicationBarIconButton.xaml.cs 1/1 files (100.00%)    
sending unbundle command    
sending 431 bytes    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
sending: 0 kb    
sending: 0 kb    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
sending: 0 kb    
sending: 0 kb    
remote: ssl required    
preparing listkeys for "phases"    
sending listkeys command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
try to push obsolete markers to remote    
checking for updated bookmarks    
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified    
[HgKeyring] Keyring URL: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone    
[HgKeyring] Cached auth data found. Url: https://bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone, user: nulldev, passwd: ********    
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
```

Comment: You should probably add a little more information, like the repo URL you're trying to push to and any other debug/warning output.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is usually due to a config issue on the server side (ie on BitBucket's side), as illustrated by this [old ticket](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/2593/getting-ssl-required-when-pushing-to-wiki) (which suddenly got a few new entries, all mentioning your error).

```
pushing to https://nulldev@bitbucket.org/nulldev/windows-phone
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: nulldev
password: 
searching for changes
remote: ssl required
```

As explained in "[Remote repos](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/)":

> What happens is that Mercurial’s webserver won’t let you push over plain HTTP by default, it requires you to use a HTTPS URL.
>   Alice can disable this requirement by using `--config web.push_ssl=No` on the command line when she serves the repository

So I suppose that on BitBucket side, they need to make sure the repo are served with:

```
hg serve --config web.push_ssl=No --config "web.allow_push=*"
```

Comment: Thats my entry there! :) Anyways, are you sure I should ask them for changes to _their_ server? Also, what if I *do* want to push my changes using SSL?

Comment: @nullDev They need to authorize https pushing, and it seems they didn't. They can configure it to authorize both. In the meantime, try indeed a push using ssh, to see if that works.

Comment: Well, the ssh wont work for me (something to do with firewall and proxy - its not my home network).

Comment: @nullDev proxy isn't an issue as long as you set the HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY environment variables. But for https only, not ssh. Ssh for external sites is always blocked at work, indeed.

Comment: The BB guys have started to work on it. They fixed this one, and now I have another - probably unrelated - issue on HTTPS. And yes, ssh is working at my home. I am going to accept this one as answer.