# Where is hgrc in my local mercurial repo?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a local mercurial repo named mercurialTest in the directory

```
/home/xyz/MERCURIAL
```

I am serving it using mercurial's web server (I used the command`hg serve`).The repo is available at

```
http://xyz-satellite-l640:8000/
```

I clonned the repo mercurialTest in the following directory

```
/home/xyz/MERCURIALWORKERS/workerOne
/home/xyz/MERCURIALWORKERS/workerTwo
```

Now I in the repo MERCURIAL which is inside workerOne , I added a file named

```
mercurialbasics.txt
```

I added and commited the file. Now I am trying to push the file to

```
/home/xyz/MERCURIAL
```

However I get the following error

```
pushing to http://xyz-satellite-l640:8000/
searching for changes
remote: ssl required
```

According to the tutorial  `http://hginit.com/02.html` I have to change something in the hgrc file that's located in `/home/xyz/MERCURIAL`

However I donot see that file.So what exactly am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093853/6309), you could modify the way you serve that repos with a:

```
hg serve --config web.push_ssl=No --config "web.allow_push=*"
```

The hgrc is usually within your home: `~/.hgrc`.

See the "[Configuration file location of Publishing Mercurial Repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Customizing_the_hgweb_script)":

> hgweb reads global and repository-specific configuration files like Mercurial does - see **[`hg help config`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/config)**. Note that it will read the .hgrc of the user the web server runs as.

As mentioned in `hg help config`, you have local, global, per-user, and system `hgrc` files.

```
<repo>/.hg/hgrc
$HOME/.hgrc
/etc/mercurial/hgrc
<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc
<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc
```

Answer (score 0):

- hgrc file for *this* repository located in `<REPO-DIR>/.hg/hgrc`
- If you prefer configure web-setting once instead of using extended command-line of `hg serve`, you can in hgrc (old good plain-text ini-file) add section with content, identical to parameters of command

`[web]`

`push_ssl = False`

`allow_push = *`

and use just `hg serve` later

**BEWARE:** these setting are somehow insecure:

- SSL not used, thus - anybody can intercept and decode data in push
- Anybody (who knows URL of repo - see above) can push to this repo any data under any name